# Не работает функция itoa()

Tags: c++, c, char

КОД:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS
char* get_name(int index)
{
    static char final_name[] = "";
    index++;
    char* number;
    char buf[20];
    char name[] = "dbase";
    char type[] = ".txt";
    number = itoa(index, buf, 10);
    strcat_s(final_name, name);
    strcat_s(final_name, number);
    strcat_s(final_name, type);
    return final_name;
}
```

Какие-то проблемы с itoa: Пишу в visual studio 2019, компилятор ругался на itoa(), и предложил добавить

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Это не помогло, но теперь он начал предлагать использовать следующее имя данной функции:

```
_itoa()
```

Это снова не решило проблему, начал выдавать ошибку ошибку об использовании safe_function и предложил назвать

```
_itoa_s()
```

Но возвращаемое значение данной функции errno_t и присваивание

```
number = _itoa_s(index, buf,10);
```

Не работает.

Как ещё можно попробовать заставить функцию itoa() работать? Или предложите какую-нибудь альтернативу для преобразования целого числа в строку, но так, чтобы моя функция char * get_name(int) работала.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `std::to_string()`, не? Но это, очевидно, C++, а не C. Поэтому с метками вопроса всё же стоит разобраться.

Comment: Перед использованием следует внимательно читать документацию, а не пытаться состряпать что-то наугад.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать to_string, но как по мне, то тут есть более проверенный старый вариант

```
#include <cstdio>


char* get_name(int index)
{
    static char final_name[300] = "";
    index++;
    snprintf(final_name, sizeof(final_name),"dbase%d.txt", index);
    return final_name;
}
```

я использую snprintf вместо sprintf для того, что бы явно буфер указать. Да, 300 символов это немного много, по факту там 20 хватит, но может завтра захочется полный путь указывать.

Но если бы я писал код для себя, то где то так бы сделал

```
std::string get_name(int index)
{
    return std::string("dbase") + std::to_string(index+1) + ".txt";
}
```

а в вызываемом коде просто

```
auto name = get_name(1);
my_f(name.c_str());
```

Или даже так c [format](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), которую в [20 стандарт](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) подвезли.

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
//#include <format> - для 20 стандарта

std::string get_name(int index)
{
    return fmt::format("dbase{0}.txt", index+1);
}
```

Но если хочется начальный вариант заставить работать, то это можно

```
char* get_name(int index)
{
    static char final_name[300] = ""; // хватит всем (ц)
    index++;
    char number[20];
    char name[] = "dbase";
    char type[] = ".txt";
    _itoa_s(index, number, sizeof(number), 10);
    strcat_s(final_name, name);
    strcat_s(final_name, number);
    strcat_s(final_name, type);
    return final_name;
}
```

Comment: 300 символов хватит каждому (ц)

Comment: MAX_PATH == 260 и в большинстве случаев это так и есть. А кто идет дальше, тот обычно понимает, что static char нужно и размера правильного задать и лучше не использовать

Comment: Одного буфера хватит каждому (ц)